# Inizialize a vector in the class constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, null, initialization

I have a class with a private attribute that is a vector. I'm Initializing it at null in the constructor like this:

```
Graph(int NumberOfVertices):vertices(NumberOfVertices),             
                                    edges(0),
                                    adjacency_list(NULL){};
```

the vector is

```
std::vector<Edge *> adjacency_list;
```

the program doesn't works, but I'm not sure that this is the error, is it right initialize a vector like I'm doing?

Comment: You don't need to initialize an empty vector, the default vector constructor works fine for that.

Comment: Also, why are you using pointers? If your goal is to share the ownership of the edges between the `vertices` class and others, consider to use a `std::shared_ptr`. Or simply represents the edges as pairs of vertices.

Comment: A vector can't be null - it's not a pointer. (You're actually initialising with 0 which is what NULL expands to.) What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Edge * is a list of edges, so every edge has a pointer to the next edge, and the one stored in the vector is the head of the list

Comment: If your compiler supports C++11, consider replacing your raw pointer with `std::forward_list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't initialize an empty vector field in your class, default constructor of vector suffices. You may however resize it in constructor if you know already the number of elements.

```
Graph(int NumberOfVertices):vertices(NumberOfVertices),             
                                    edges(0) { adjacency_list.resize(vertices)};
```

This is definitely incorrect:

```
adjacency_list(NULL) // this will evaluate to vector(0) 
                     // and your vector has 0 size
```

probably you've confused the pointers that vector stores with the vector itself. Initializing class vector with NULL will evaluate to a vector with 0 size. **There is no need to initialize an empty `vector` instance which is a class member**:

> Default initialization is performed in three situations:
>
> 1) when a variable with automatic storage duration is declared with
>   no initializer
>
> 2) when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a
>   new-expression without an initializer
>
> 3) when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in
>   a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.  <<< aha
>
> The effects of default initialization are:
>
> If T is a class type, the default constructor is called to provide the
>   initial value for the new object.
>
> If T is an array type, every element of the array is
>   default-initialized. Otherwise, nothing is done.
>
> If T is a const-qualified type, it must be a class type with a
>   user-provided default constructor.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the first element of the vector to be initialized with NULL, use the following constructor:

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type() );
```

in the following way:

```
adjacency_list( 1, NULL )
```